# Knockout newbie, can anyone spot why this doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I created a MVC 4.0 project to test Knockout, the mark up is shown below (BTW I loaded all the latest stuff from NUGET) What is shown below is the client side source after the rendering of the View from MVC.  I've looked at the network side and saw all the links and scripts arrive at the client.  Browser is Chrome.  The console doesn't show any errors.  Finally, the myMessage text is never rendered. If I put breakpoints in the JS, I do see that the Knockout library is called...  Just wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>

        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Index</h2>
        Today's message is: <span data-bind="text: myMessage"></span>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var viewModel = {
                myMessage: ko.observable() // Initially blank
            };
            viewModel.myMessage("Hello, world!"); // Text appears
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call ko.applyBindings. try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var viewModel = {
                myMessage: ko.observable() // Initially blank
            };
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel) // you need to initialize ko :)
            viewModel.myMessage("Hello, world!"); // Text appears
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, I had started on the Text Bindings page and copied that code directly.  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html  Maybe they are applying bindings elsewhere....

Comment: Just to add something else to this which you should get into the habit of doing with KO.  Hint your observables.  If you intend to put strings in then "blah = ko.observable('')" , if a bool then "ko.observable(false)" and so on, it helps KO prepare a few things ahead of time if it knows what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

well you missed the most important part in knockout 'applyBindings' .

Once you construct your view model you just need to call

**Step 1:** Starting point

```
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

**step 2:** next view model executes

```
var viewModel = {
                myMessage: ko.observable() 
            };
```

Refer knockout documentation `http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html`

Sample fiddle to test your scenario [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/20924/)

Comment: Ya, I did miss that, but the knockout site itself showed it that way... I started looking at Text Binding first and the example above was taken right from their site.

Comment: oh i see . take a look at this for applyBindings just in case http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: One question on the observable design, is this the same thing as Reactive Extensions?